# How to make CSS menu to open menu in in up direction rather than default down direction

Tags: drop-down-menu, css

I have similar CSS base menu which by default pops down i am not sure which property to change so that menu Pops up in UP Direction. more like a drop-up Menu
I have put some code of jsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/EAE4m/

I would appreciate help on this. I have looked for similar example could not find one which fits in my scenario.

**UPDATE**:
Solution http://jsfiddle.net/EAE4m/45/

```
li ul {
display: none;
position: absolute;
width:100px;
bottom: 18px;
left: 0;
margin-left:-1px;
}
```

Comment: Managed to make it work by change properties example http://jsfiddle.net/EBkKe/

Comment: Perhaps use the `bottom` CSS and set it to match the main menu's top?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
top: 18px;
```

to

```
bottom: 18px;
```